# Where are default snippets stored for MonoDevelop on OS X

Tags: macos, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm trying to find the default snippets that MonoDevelop uses.  Specifically, I'd like the change the default `prop` snippet to have in-line `get; set;` instead of separate lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find them under Preferences -> Text Editor -> Code Templates. Select the template you want and click the Edit button on the right.